# Gerar backup do banco via aplicação

Tags: sql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc-5

Em meu projeto faço a ligação com o banco de dados.

Existe alguma forma de eu fazer o *backup* do meu banco de dados via aplicação *asp.net mvc 5* e guardar esse *backup* em um diretório, seja na raiz do projeto ou em uma pasta em um lugar mais seguro?

O banco de dados que uso é o `SQL Server Express 2012`.

Comment: Relacionado: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/39978/backup-database-sqlserver

Comment: Acredito que se tomarmos por base a pergunta linkada pelo @gmsantos (bem como a resposta dada por lá), basta chamar aqueles comandos com o método [SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Mas não tenho 100% de certeza. Se alguém verificar que isso é correto e postar como resposta, terá meu +1.

Comment: Fazendo isso pelo código c# ? Porque pelo que vi na resposta é somente pelo SQL Server mesmo.

Comment: Mais alguém? Será que existe então alguma forma de fazer um script e colocar no projeto e executar aquele script via aplicação ?

Comment: Eu queria entender o porquê de uma aplicação ter que gerar e restaurar o backup de um banco de dados. Pra mim não faz o menor sentido.

Comment: Não preciso restaurar, somente gerar. Também não sei, mas se o cliente pediu, vou colocar né. Eu até entendo. Mesmo que o banco crie, e isso seja automatizado, seria mais uma forma de gerar o backup caso não funcione a outra forma.

Comment: E como faço pra restaurar ou pra usar um determinado backup mas pela visão também?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

É possível sim.
Você precisa montar no seu código C# o comando sql de *backup* e executá-lo, algo como:

Abrir a conexão e montar uma *query* que executa o comando para fazer o *backup* conforme o caminho desejado para salvar o seu *backup*

```
public void ExecutarBackup(string caminho)
{ 
    suaConexao = new SqlConnection(...);
    var query = "Backup database NomeSeuBanco to disk='" + caminho + "'";
    var cmd = new SqlCommand(query, suaConexao);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

---

**Edição/Complemento:**

> E como que eu faria pra colocar em uma view ? Como se fosse um botão ? Ou algo do tipo.

Sua *View* pode ter um controle para o usuário informar o caminho em que ele deseja salvar o *backup* e um botão. Ao clicar no botão ocorre o Post para uma *Action* do seu *Controller*, passando o caminho que o usuário deseja salvar o *backup* como parâmetro.

Essa *Action* pode chamar um serviço/método para gerar o *backup*.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SalvarBakup(SeuViewModel seuViewModel)
{
    _servicoBackup.ExecutarBackup(seuViewModel.Caminho);
    return View();
}
```

Abaixo exemplifico a View:

```
@model SeuViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm("SalvarBakup", "SeuController"))
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Caminho)
    <input type="submit" value="Salvar Backup" />
}
```

Comment: E como que eu faria pra colocar em uma *view* ? Como se fosse um botão ? Ou algo do tipo.

Comment: AQui: *model => model.Caminho*, eu teria que criar uma tabela ? Ou ele já reconhece a variável que esta na *Action* ?

Comment: Teria como nesse *post* ao invés de o usuário digitar o caminha, ele escolher onde quer salvar ? Tipo quando se baixa um PDF, por exemplo ?

Comment: A View é tipada (no exemplo acima ela é do tipo SeuViewModel). SeuViewModel é uma classe que representa o seu Model. O ideal é que as propriedades que estejam na View estejam nessa classe. model => model.Caminho não tem relação com criação de tabela, apenas significa que um controle textbox vai ser renderizado na View e seu valor será enviado no post. Dê estudada sobre View Model Pattern. Aproveitei para editar e deixar a resposta mais clara.

Comment: Entendi. De qualquer forma, eu teria que ter um Model com o atributo Caminho e setar um valor nele. Certo ?

Comment: Tem como fazer sem um Model. Mas seguindo a estrutura do Asp.Net MVC o correto é você ter a classe de Model sim.

Comment: Agora sim ! Devo editar a pergunta e colocar uma dica a mais ali. Mas valeu pela resposta ! Se der erro, te aviso !

Comment: estou tendo erro de permissão pra acessar qualquer diretório e salvar o .bak... Como que faço ?